# How to deploy next.js + express app to Zeit now UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning noserverpages built

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy my application which is next.js + express server just to handle some socket connection.

This is how my project directory looks like:

[image]

next.config.js:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({

    webpack: config => {




      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
            name: '[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      })

      return config
    }
  })
```

now.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {"src": "package.json", "use": "@now/next"},
        { "src": "server.js", "use": "@now/node" }
    ]
  }
```

scripts part of package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "now-build": "next build",

    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  }
```

errors i get:
server.js:

```
Error: No serverless pages were built. https://err.sh/zeit/now-builders/now-next-no-serverless-pages-built
    at Object.exports.build (/tmp/26a0d565/.build-utils/.builder/node_modules/@now/next/dist/index.js:275:19)
    at <anonymous>
```

package.json:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Data must be a string or a buffer
    at Hash.update (crypto.js:99:16)
    at ids.forEach.id (/tmp/2d245f3b/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/hashed-chunk-ids-plugin.js:24:41)
```

If i follow the instructions on the link for serverless error i still get the same error.

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({
  target: 'serverless',

    webpack: config => {




      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
            name: '[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      })

      return config
    }
  })
```

If i remove now.json and then deploy it just lists folder on page.There is a lot going on internet about those errors but i couldnt solve it

Comment: I think that it's not possible with now 2 use now 1 instead but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const cssConfig = withCSS({
  webpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: {
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
          limit: 100000,
          name: "[name].[ext]"
        }
      }
    });

    return config;
  }
});
module.exports = Object.assign(cssConfig, { target: "serverless" });
```

I think the config is not merged properly. You can do a quick check by `console.log(cssConfig)` if `target:serverless` is exists on the config.